# How do you print out lines from a file that match a certain condition, but you have many columns to check?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
name played wins loses
Leeroy,19,7,12
Jenkins,19,8,11
Tyler,19,0,19
Napoleon Wilson,19,7,12
Big Boss,19,7,12
Game Dude,19,5,14
Macho Man,19,3,16
Space Pirate,19,6,13
Billy Casper,19,7,12
Otacon,19,7,12
Big Brother,19,7,12
Ingsoc,19,5,14
Ripley,19,5,14
M'lady,19,4,15
Einstein100,19,8,11
Dennis,19,5,14
Esports,19,8,11
RNGesus,19,7,12
Kes,19,9,10
Magnitude,19,6,13
```

Basically, this is a file called `firesideResults`, which i open in my code and i have to check through it. If the win column contains a 0 i do not print it out, so if it contains a number other than zero i display it on the screen. However, i have multiple lists of numbers to deal with and i can't find how to only deal with one column of numbers.

my code was going to be

```
if option == ("C") or option == ("c"):
    answer = False
    file_3 = open("firesideResults.txt")
    for column in file_3:
        if ("0" not in column):
            print(column)
```

But unfortunately, one of the other columns of code contain a 0 so i cannot do that. Thank you for your help and if possible please list any questions that i could check for help as i have been searching for so long.

Comment: Please format your code; at present, it is unreadable.

Comment: sorry it is a bit difficult to format but i will fix it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have comma-separated fields, the best way would be to use `csv`!

```
import csv

with open("firesideResults.txt") as file_3:
    cr = csv.reader(file_3)
    for row in cr:
        if row[2]!="0":
            print(row)
```

if third column of each row is not 0, then print it.

- no substring issue: checks for exact field
- checks for field at the "win" column only, not the other ones.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try that now

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I will investigate csv further and research more things i can import.

Comment: sorry could I just ask, is cr just a simple variable or does it have a connection with csv.

Comment: it's just a variable name.